# Laravel Forge permissions issue

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu-20.04, laravel-9, laravel-forge

I'm having issues with file permissions on my forge site. Files that are uploaded can't be downloaded again. I ran `sudo chmod g+rwxs storage` and then it worked, but later stopped working. My assumption is that running a deployment is resetting those permissions or something. Do I need to add that command to my deployment script or something? Any ideas on what could be causing this?

I tried adding the command to my deployment script but I get this error:

`sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper`

No idea what askpass helper is, and wasn't sure about including the password with the -S flag. Not sure if that's a bad idea from a security standpoint.